# Cash app withdrawal transaction not found

Tags: transactions

I submitted for a withdrawal on Cash App about 4 hours. A go and so far, It still says transaction not found and the little circle just keeps spinning. I have a second transaction as well for today. That is doing the exact same thing. I had a couple other transactions that went through. No problem, but these 2 have been stuck for several hours with nothing found. Here are the transaction id's:

6eaf9a995a93aae4480375997eeac500547ff00edf4abfeffae3aab595544ce8

0e20f488180b3506b3ca737a635cd85f126631ab384b8d8ad15f77db44afdf20

Answer (score 1):

Both transaction IDs show as confirmed (about 3 hours after question was posted here) and as having a fee of 1 satoshi per vbyte

That fee rate is low and accounts for any delay in confirmation.